# How do I create an Entity automatically with DateTime.Now, instead of the user specify the value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

Using ASP.NET MVC4, I have a CreateView, where the user specify Author, Text and CreateTime.
I don't want the user to see or fill in the CreateTime, I want my code to do it automatically somehere using `DateTime.Now.ToShortDateTime()`.

It's this part in my CreateView I want to chance.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreateTime)
```

EDIT: Here is my CreateView:

```
@model Models.Topic


@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Topic</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Author)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Author)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Author)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreateTime)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreateTime)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreateTime)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Remove the line and just add the `DateTime.Now` elsewhere in the program? For example when you send your object to a repository or however you communicate with your datasource.

Comment: It's a little difficult to suggest a valid change without seeing the rest of your `CreateView` method.

Comment: That was my first thought too. But after using this view I feel like it's all getting done, right down to inserting it to the Db. So I kinda feel like I don't have the possiblity anymore.

Comment: I don't see why you don't have that option anymore. Could you expand on that?

Comment: What is the CreateTime used for? Is it the time stamp when someone started to create your model or time when it was saved in the database?

Comment: @BarisaPuter It's a time stamp for when they created a new Topic in the database.

Comment: Ok, then I'll give you an example how to deal with this globally - more efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want things not to be set by user do not put on html like hidden fields or any where else .

its better to exclude after posting in action method

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult  FormPostAction([Bind(Exclude = "CreateTime")] Topic topic)
{
and here you have to initialize CreateTime with whatever value you want...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I should you Post attribute, because im updating in DB. And the exclude Bind, suits just this type of task. And the great thing is that i learned that i get back to C# code and it all dosnt magically disappear after the view :)

Answer (score 2):

Create a hidden input via an html helper:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CreateTime)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can set the default value for editor

```
@Html.EditorFor( model => model.CreateTime, 
                                        new { @Value = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() })
```

Comment: Ah, this look like something that could work. I tryed with "@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreateTime, new { @Value = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() })" (You have a " ," to much, and it's "ToShortDateString()". But it has no effect. Did we miss anything as the second parameter?

Answer (score 1):

First you define an interface

```
public interface ICreatedTracked
{
     DateTime CreateTime {get;set;}
}
```

Then you have all your tracked models inherit from it, i.e.:

```
public class SomeModel : ICreatedTracked
{
... your properties
public DateTime CreateTime {get;set;}
}
```

Then you override SaveChanges on your DbContext like this:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
    {
    IEnumerable<DbEntityEntry<ICreatedTracked>> timeStampedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries<ICreatedTracked>();

    if (timeStampedEntities != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in timeStampedEntities.Where(t => t.State == EntityState.Added))
                item.Entity.Created = DateTime.Now;
       }
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

This way you don't have to set the value up each time you create any of your entities that you want to have CreateTime property.

Comment: It looks very interesting, but why do I need a `foreach` when I am only saving one `Message`? Remember I came from a CreateView that creates one Message. Are you thinking about another scenario than me? Do I miss something? The ChangeTracker is new to me too, but beside that, I like the Interface and the override though.

Comment: This is general approach. You might be in situation where you want to save several entities to the database in single transaction (by calling SavingChanges).